# windows server 2012 r2 network share does not reconnect after client reboot

Tags: network-shares, domain, windows-server-2012-r2

i have got a windows server 2012 r2 server which hosts multiple network shares in a local domain.

i connect from multiple (win7) clients using domain credentials, and everything works just fine. folder permissions are correct and work as expected.

but the issue is: if i reboot the client (NOT the server), the shares wont reconnect, giving the following error:

> Fehler bei der erneuten Verbindungsherstellung von Z: mit \\myserver\myshare
>
> Microsoft Windows Network: Der angegebene Benutzername ist unzulässig.

which roughly translates to

> Error while trying to reconnect to Z: on \\myserver\myshare
>
> Microsoft Windows Network: Specified user name is invalid

the username IS valid, it works when i connected before reboot and it works again if i remove the network drive and reconect manually.

what could be the problem?

thanks in advance for your help,

Christian.